# Serve static folder with symfony 4

Tags: symfony, static, serve

I want to copy my dist folder generated by Vue.js and serve it on a symfony route, I tried:

**routes.yaml**

```
vue:
  path: /{path}
  controller: App\Controller\ApiController::vue
  methods: [GET]
  requirements:
    path: .*
```

**ApiController.php**

```
public function vue()
{
    $vuepath = __DIR__.'/../../public/dist/index.html';
    return new Response(file_get_contents($vuepath));
}
```

It starts `index.html` does not load the javascript files. How can I serve my application?

Comment: The default `.htaccess` (from the `symfony/apache-pack` package) should already just serve static files as is - did you modify it in any way?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I also need to serve everything unter public/dist  (directory -> index.html and files)

Answer (score 0):

This is simple (no support for the url rewrite - when you want to serve spa on some path other than site root) controller I've made for the serving of the spa folder from arbitrary folder.

This implementation brings the benefit of having the symfony profiler toolbar - to help with debugging/profiling the ajax/fetch requests.

However I would recommend another approach for production - create a separate deployment for the spa app.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Path;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\MimeTypesInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

#[Route(
   path: '/',
)]
class SpaController
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly MimeTypesInterface $mimeTypes,
        private readonly string             $documentRootPath,
        private readonly string             $indexFile,
    )
    {
    }

    #[Route(
        path: '/{urlPath}',
        requirements: [
            'urlPath' => '.*',
        ],
        utf8: true,
    )]
    public function spaIndex(string $urlPath): Response
    {
        if ('' === $urlPath) {
            $urlPath = $this->indexFile;
        }

        if ($this->indexFile !== $urlPath) {
            $filePath = Path::canonicalize($this->documentRootPath . $urlPath);
            if (
                Path::isBasePath($this->documentRootPath, $filePath)
                && is_file($filePath)
            ) {
                $fileResponse = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);

                $ext = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                // symfony guessMimeType returns the wrong mime [`text/plain`] type for `.js`
                $mimeType = $this->mimeTypes->getMimeTypes($ext)[0] ?? null;
                if ($mimeType) {
                    $fileResponse->headers->set('Content-Type', $mimeType);
                }

                return $fileResponse;
            }
            // fallback to serving the indexFile bellow
        }

        // for symfony to inject the debug toolbar one must use response with text contents
        $indexFileContents = file_get_contents($this->documentRootPath . $this->indexFile);
        $response = new Response($indexFileContents);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/html');

        return $response;
    }
}
```